# C# about object creating

Tags: c#, class, oop, object

I know how to create an object.

```
Class1 name = new Class1();
```

This means create an object from Class1 but i saw some code on the internet and i didn't get it. I wanted to search google about that question. But i don't know what i am supposed to search. Can you help me understand that?

```
Class1 name = new Class2();
```

What is that mean? I mean, am i creating an object from Class1? Am i creating an object from Class2? or am i creating an object from both Class1 and Class2 classes?

Comment: Search for “inheritance”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second example your specify

```
Class1 name = new Class2();
```

That is saying that Class2 inherits from Class1 also, so it contains the functionality of Class1 and also Class2. But becuase you declared it as Class1, you will can only use Class1 functionality in your program.

But that is the simple explanation. Class1 could actually be an interface that Class2 actually implements, or Class1 could be an abstract base class which must be inherited. You could cast name to Class2 and get both Class1 and Class2 functionality.
Without a concrete example of what you are proposing it almost impossible to understand the the kind of answer you are looking for.

Comment: Actually, i think i got it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code compiles, we can confidently say that `Class2` inherits `Class1`.

When you perform the following operation:

```
Class1 name = new Class2();
```

you're creating an instance/object of `Class2` but the type of the variable is `Class1`. This is perfectly valid as `Class2` derives from `Class1`.

As long as you know that the `new` operator is what creates an object we can, therefore, say that whatever type follows the `new` operator is the type of object that is being constructed.

That's all, there's nothing more to it.